# ExecutionPolicy changed automatically

Tags: security, powershell, remote-execution

I set execution policy in the powershell console

```
set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
get-ExecutionPolicy bypass ==> return bypass
```

and then wait couple minutes, check the policy level again

```
get-ExecutionPolicy bypass ==> return remotesigned
```

I don't understand why it occurs.
Does anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1):

The policy probably reverted back due to Group Policy being applied. To check if that's true, run **gpupdate** at the command prompt immediately after setting the execution policy to bypass and see if it reverts back to remotesigned.